# RESTful API call using C#

Tags: c#, rest, security, authorization, api-design

I am building my URL to make an API call, using the key and secret that the provider has given me.

https://api.testurl.com/api/test/calldata?key=12345&secret=999999&query=hello

My question is I am appending the 'query' based on user input each time and performing the call with the 'key' and 'secret' every time - to me this doesn't seem that secure. Isn't the secret key exposed each time the call is made?

```
public async Task<List<APIResult.Data>> ApiAsync()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(_apiUrlToCall);

    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) return null;
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var rootResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIResult.Rootobject>
        (result);
        return rootResult.Data.ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you'd pass the identity data (in this case your key and secret) in a HTTP header rather than on the querystring. That way it doesn't get logged anywhere (e.g. IIS logs, browser history, slurped by google, facebook *et al* trackers).

If you're using HTTPS that should stop it being exposed anywhere else.

But yes since HTTP is *stateless* you have to send some sort of identifying data every time you make a request, be that a secret key, Kerberos token, session coookie, whatever it is.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the key & secret as Http header. Normally for rest api the Authorization Http Header is set with the authtoken. You could so something similar.